# Build with dependency in gcp artifact registry

Tags: maven, google-cloud-platform, artifact

Building an application with a dependency to google cloud platform artifact registry results in an error:

```
Cannot access artifactregistry://us-central1-maven.pkg.dev/project/repository with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access artifactregistry://us-central1-maven.pkg.dev/project/repository using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add com.google.cloud.artifactregistry maven extension to your pom.xml (not covered in the documentation), it is not enough with repositories, distributionmanagement and dependency.

```
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.artifactregistry</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifactregistry-maven-wagon</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

Comment: Setting up Artifact Registry in Maven is still on Alpha as of this writing. This is now included in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/quickstart#config-maven)